# Keyboard turns on computer despite BIOS setting

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I'm currently using a Steelseries 6gv2 keyboard, and pressing a button turns on my computer.

Now I went into the BIOS and checked all the power button settings and anything involving powering up upon a key press is turned off. Neither any usage of the mouse or the keyboard should, according to the BIOS settings, be turning on my computer. But the keyboard does.

So what can I do here? Is there any other setting somewhere outside of the BIOS that I missed?

Comment: Are you sure the computer is off and not just sleeping?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely shut down.